# nginx rewrite rule to server images from subdomain?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'd like all my images (jpg|gif|png) which currently being serversd from mydomain.com/files/ to be servered from a second machine which I've set up to server files from static.mydomain.com.

I am wondering how should I define nginx rewrite rule to do so?

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done to figure this out for yourself?

Comment: I've googled and also looked at similar ServerFault questions but could not find any solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy pass:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

In your case this could be something like:

```
location /mydomain.com/files/.*\.(jpg|gif|png) {
       proxy_pass http://static.mydomain.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that minniux's solution is not a rewrite, but will cause all traffic to pass through the "redirecting" host. This is not what *I* would want.

Use the *rewrite* directive instead:

```
location /files/.*\.(jpg|gif|png) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ "$scheme://static.mydomain.com/$1" permanent;
}
```

You don't need to make the `rewrite`'s regex more complex; the `location` block already affects only matching requests.

The `$scheme` variable allows you to redirect to *https* or *http* depending on the original scheme.

PS: A redirect will also void the pain of caring for `X-Forwarded-*` header fields on the *static* server.